# Negative Border Radius in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to do CSS to make a div that looks like this:
[image: negative left margin]

I'm pretty much started with this:

```
.player {
    width: 480px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}
```

Whats the simplest way to do this, without too much code?

Answer (score 20):

Here's [yet another way of doing it](https://jsfiddle.net/Auroratide/1cy260x8/), this time using a radial background image.  This lets it be transparent and works in both Firefox and Chrome.

```css
.player {
  width: 480px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 38px 40px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40px, blue 40px);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="player"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to work in IE 11 at least as well, with maybe a minor tweak for positioning

Comment: work in opera as well, thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `before` pseudo element to provide the "cut out"

```css
.player {
    width: 480px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius:0 40px 40px 0;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    position:relative;    
    color:#FFF;
}

.player:before
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius:0 40px 40px 0;
    background-color:#FFF;    
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="player">Some Content</div>
```

Comment: Nice!  I was honestly a little surprised to see this was possible.

Comment: The problem is, I need the indent to be transparent, not white;

Comment: We're not quite there yey, but coming soon `clip-path` : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path & https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

Comment: The missing element is shadow.  Make the :before transparent and add a shadow.

Comment: I have modified your snippet and posted it as a separate answer.  See the delta - transparent circle instead of white and with a shadow.

Answer (score 7):

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 103px;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.player {
    width: 480px;
    height: 83px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at left, transparent 0, transparent 40px, black 41px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="player"></div></div>
```

Comment: The problem is, I need the indent to be transparent, not white;

Answer (score 5):

Jon P's answer is almost there - but the before element can be used to make a transparent circle to the left of the main div and a shadow produces the desired cut-out effect.

```css
body {
  /* You can change the background colour to verify that this is truly transparent */
  background-color: pink;
}

.player {
    /* Just a normal box */
    width: 480px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius:0 40px 40px 0;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    position:relative;    
    color:#FFF;
   /* Move the box right so that we can see the cutout to the left */
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.player:before
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius:0 40px 40px 0;
    background-color:transparent;    
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '';
    /* This is the cutout: */
    box-shadow: 40px 0px #00f;
    position: relative;
    left: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">Some Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking like that too, but I got a better way, I used a svg as a background. It also has the advantage of being more responsive. I will send my problem here to other people who will also have the same question.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/XiH.svg) center right;
    background-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
p {
  width: 480px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 1in;
  box-shadow:inset -400px 0 #03214f,inset 9in 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>
```