# React Native corner styling FlatList component

Tags: css, react-native

I am having trouble styling the corner edges of the FlatList's list component as per the provided design by our designer. I am able to achieve borderBottomLeftRadius and now I want to curve-out the Top Left Corner as per the design (like if you try to pinch and pull out one of the corner of a rectangle), please help me achieve this using the styling to match the below design:

[image]

What I am able to do is:

style:

```
width: wp('100%'),
padding: hp('4.5%'),
marginVertical: 0,
borderBottomLeftRadius: 100
```

UI using above style:

[image]

Comment: The easiest solution I can see is to apply a negative margin-top to your secondary components.

Comment: @Jake I did, the FlatList cells just overlaps but wouldn't spike out or pinch out from top-left corner

Comment: What do you mean by spike out or pinch out ? Do you mean that they are not accessible by touch when applying negative margins ? If so, apply absolutely positioned pseudo elements to replicate these shapes ?

Comment: @Jake I mean the bottom left corner is curved-in and I want to curve-out top left corner, like if you try to pinch and pull out one of the corner of a rectangle

Comment: In that case, as I said, use a pseudo selector such as :before or :after to draw the curve-out (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339986/negative-border-radius-in-css for an exemple)