# How to have overlapping pill progress bars

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a progress bar in bootstrap with both projected and actual results on it, however the design desire is to have a rounded "pill" shape on the right hand edge. The following snippet shows what I have been able to achieve:

```js
const data = {
    actual: 1155,
  projected: 1573,
  limits: [500, 1000, 2500]
};

const actualProgress = document.getElementById("actual-progress");
const projectedProgress = document.getElementById("projected-progress");

const barLength = Math.max(...data.limits);
const actualPercentage = (data.actual / barLength) * 100;
const projectedPercentage = ((data.projected - data.actual) / barLength) * 100;

actualProgress.style.width = `${actualPercentage}%`;
projectedProgress.style.width = `${projectedPercentage}%`;
```

```css
.progress-bar.bg-actual {
  background: #b445f5;
}

.progress-bar.bg-projected {
  background: #d391fa;
}

.progress-bar {
  border-radius: 0 500px 500px 0;
}

.progress {
  border-radius: 500px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="progress">
        <div id="actual-progress" class="progress-bar bg-actual"></div>
        <div id="projected-progress" class="progress-bar bg-projected"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like is for the lighter purple to fill the small slivers left by the rounded edge of the darker purple, while still having a consistent way to set the width of the bars by percentage. Any help would be appreciated.

### Edit:

Thanks to *Tasos Bu* and their answer I was able to find a full solution that fitted my intention including covering edge cases and having the actual portion of the bar terminate at the desired point. The fiddle for this can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wkbs67jm/88/) if anyone in the future wants to see it.

### Final Edit:

After more playing around I finally achieved the full desired functionality, that anyone viewing this might find useful: [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wkbs67jm/310/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a pseudo-element before the second bar and remove the radius of the first one:
Related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339986/negative-border-radius-in-css#)

**EDIT**: Keep in mind that this will "push" the first bar a little bit to the right, so you should handle this when setting its width with javascript.

```js
const data = {
    actual: 1155,
  projected: 1573,
  limits: [500, 1000, 2500]
};

const actualProgress = document.getElementById("actual-progress");
const projectedProgress = document.getElementById("projected-progress");

const barLength = Math.max(...data.limits);
const actualPercentage = (data.actual / barLength) * 100;
const projectedPercentage = ((data.projected - data.actual) / barLength) * 100;

actualProgress.style.width = `${actualPercentage}%`;
projectedProgress.style.width = `${projectedPercentage}%`;
```

```css
.progress-bar.bg-actual {
  background: #b445f5;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.progress-bar.bg-projected {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-bar.bg-projected:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius:0 500px 500px 0;
  background-color: #b445f5;    
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
}

.progress-bar {
  border-radius: 0 500px 500px 0;
}


.progress {
  border-radius: 500px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="progress">
        <div id="actual-progress" class="progress-bar bg-actual"></div>
        <div id="projected-progress" class="progress-bar bg-projected"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. After you posted this answer I was able to take the idea of using pseudo-elements and create a solution I was fully happy with including having the "actual" bar terminating in the expected location with the use of the css calc function.